# how to change html button class and functionality?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

Simply what I want is to to **change the button class and value** in order to change the button **functionality**.

what happening is that the value and the class are **changed successfully** BUT the **functionality remain the same as for the old class**
why?!

does the browser store the jquery code somewhere and load from it?! and how can i refresh it in that case??

here's piece of my code:
*(I'm using Jquery Ajax with html and php)*

```
    var target_button; // global variable to store the target button

    $(".activateButton").click(function(){

        var serial_number = $(target_button).attr("id");
        var cvc = $("#cvc").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '../ajax/tag.php',
            data:
            {
                s: serial_number,
                c: cvc
            }
        }).done(function(data)
            {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (result == "1")
                {
                    $("#message").text('Tag Successfully Activated');
                    $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
                    $(target_button).attr("value", "Disable");
                    $(target_button).removeClass("popActivateButton");    //<---------- REPLACING THE CLASS
                    $(target_button).addClass("enableDisableButton");     //<----------

                }
```

here's the buttons:

```
    if($tags[$i]['Status'] == 1){
        $button = "<input type=\"button\" class=\"enableDisableButton\" id=\"".$tags[$i]['SerialNumber']."\" value=\"Disable\"/>";
    }
    if($tags[$i]['Status'] == 2){
        $button = "<input type=\"button\" class=\"popActivateButton\" id=\"".$tags[$i]['SerialNumber']."\" value=\"Activate\"/>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a selector it selects all elements that match at the time you execute the code. Previously called selectors - even if cached - do **not** dynamically update when new elements that match them are added to the page.

If you've bound event handlers to elements, then they're going to stay there until you a. remove the event handler(s), or b. remove the element entirely. Just changing the class isn't going to magically change the event handlers that are bound.

I'd suggest using event delegation instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.enableDisableButton', function() {
    //your code for enableDisableButton
}).on('click', '.popActivateButton', function() {
    // your code for popActivateButton
});
```

With event delegation the selector is checked when the event is triggered, rather than when the code executes, so it **will** reflect changes to the page.

Note that I've used `document` in the code example above. However, you should instead use a selector for a static element (one that won't be removed) that will contain the elements you want to execute the event handler function for; the closer it is in the DOM structure to the dynamic elements the better.

Comment: But how do I change the functionality of the button in that case!?
I want to keep responding to the same event 'Click' but do a totally different job.

Comment: @MahmoudZalt Which button are we talking about here? The `.activateButton` one, or the one that switches class between `enableDisableButton` and `popActiveButton`? If it's the latter, you use the code in my answer and simply put the corresponding code in the correct function. The first one handles a click on the button when it has the class `enableDisableButton`, the second handles a click on the button when it has the class `popActivateButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes once event assigned you need to clear those previous events and bind new events to each.

suppose you have `button` and you have assigned `click` event now unfortunately you want to clear `click event` and something else you can do it as below,

```
$(SOMESELECTOR).unbind('previous_event').bind('new_event');
```

.

For more search for `jQuery bind and unBind`.

Comment: Or you could use the `.on()` and `.off()` functions, which are the correct ones if you're using jQuery 1.7+. Still, constantly removing and adding event handlers is likely going to be worse than other methods of handling the same issue.